# django resource get all fields ( manytomany,foreign key etc.)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

As you can see from my question, I want to download data from all other relevant tables from the users table.

```
class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['__all__'] # But I want ALL FIELDS ( foreign key fields etc.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `fields = '__all__'`, not `fields = ['__all__']`. And when you want to add the extra field, you can set the `extra_fields` attribute.

```
...
fields = '__all__'
extra_fields = ['extra']
```